# Howto setup Flexbox to always have 3 Columns?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm creating a site with Flexbox to align the items. I have the `div .main` containing the content `divs`. This is the CSS:

```
.main{
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*max-height: 2400px;*/
  max-width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Now there is only one long long column, if I don't set a height. Is there a way to always keep 3 columns and let the height set as low as possible but still high enough to display all the content?

Here is a fiddle: jsfiddle.net/m8kL9zje
If one adds some Content divs, they'll start to form a 4th column. I want them to increase the height

Comment: Why do you have `flex-wrap` if you want them all on the same row?

Comment: I want them in columns, not in rows. the flex-wrap is to create the columns

Comment: So... you want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/xu5y0aL2/ Or am I missing something...

Comment: I want my Content to be side by side. In 3 Columns, from top to bottom. Each columns should contain about the same amount of content divs. The problem is that without a set height it would only be in one column and not 3.

Comment: `flex-direction` controls which direction to write in.  Top to bottom - column.  Or left to right - row.  Sounds like you want a *row* of 3 columns, right?  If that is the case, you want your parent container to be `flex-direction: row`.

Comment: @NiklasFett, please setup fiddle, or snippet, if possible. It is not completely clear what is problem.

Comment: @NiklasFett it sounds like your a bit confused about flexbox, do you want a result like https://jsfiddle.net/wcjk06xm/?

Comment: Sorry for being so confusing. I want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m8kL9zje/ Now the only problem I have is that I need to set the Height manually, or all will be in one column. I want the height to set itself to be as low as possible and still maintain the 3 columns

Comment: Why can't you just do something like https://jsfiddle.net/m8kL9zje/2/?

Comment: because the content divs have different heights and I want them not to have  whitespace between them. The rows will have the height of the tallest div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need flexbox for this. Just you the css `columns` property.

```css
.content {
  background: #ccc;
  columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In dignissim quis tortor in vulputate. In malesuada augue in risus imperdiet, id tempus velit vehicula. Phasellus luctus sem in venenatis ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
  elit. Suspendisse tempus mauris vel rutrum eleifend. Nulla lectus magna, suscipit ac nunc eget, blandit pretium dolor. Nam nec eros vel diam malesuada placerat id et quam. Curabitur nisl neque, mattis id ornare egestas, faucibus non urna. Nunc pulvinar
  mattis placerat. Donec nec venenatis nulla, vel aliquam turpis. Nullam pretium massa a lacus eleifend venenatis non vel neque. Etiam at turpis pretium, consectetur dolor sed, sagittis risus. In varius vehicula mi, sed volutpat nunc feugiat in. Mauris
  consequat velit vel lectus vulputate, non facilisis nibh suscipit. Maecenas blandit nisl at orci congue cursus. Curabitur egestas quam mollis dui viverra, at lacinia nunc viverra. Donec ac lectus velit. Vestibulum sodales quam ac cursus vehicula. Cum
  sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque finibus lorem id diam aliquet hendrerit. In sollicitudin ac justo sed congue. Vivamus in egestas turpis. Mauris id tempus mi. Nam nec ligula porttitor, sagittis
  augue vitae, tristique velit. Sed ut lobortis mauris. In tempor urna eget rutrum condimentum. Nulla facilisi. Donec tincidunt pharetra libero sed aliquet. Donec eu nibh in libero ullamcorper gravida. Nullam vel dapibus purus. Etiam feugiat tortor at
  mauris accumsan, sit amet vehicula nisl mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent id diam tincidunt, fringilla eros eu, bibendum urna. Proin eu ultricies tellus. Sed in ante ultricies, blandit eros nec, ultricies elit. Integer quis aliquet
  velit. Vestibulum condimentum orci mauris, in faucibus libero aliquam nec. Etiam id ornare ante. Integer odio leo, malesuada ac dignissim eget, ornare eu magna. Duis et metus ipsum. Quisque tortor velit, imperdiet vitae pulvinar et, eleifend tincidunt
  erat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aliquam suscipit arcu nulla, vitae tempus urna sollicitudin ac. Curabitur hendrerit porttitor elit et varius. Suspendisse fringilla, libero et euismod malesuada, eros arcu vulputate
  lorem, quis elementum velit ipsum non nulla. Donec ac nulla ac urna tincidunt sodales. Etiam efficitur nibh sed tempus facilisis. Fusce efficitur lacus mi, a molestie orci pulvinar a. Maecenas id risus elit. Proin eu tortor posuere, rutrum justo in,
  varius lacus.</div>
```

Comment: Wow, never heard of the columns style! Thank you very very much! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Just keep in mind that `columns` still has very limited browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=column

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for noticing. But it's fine for me. I need this for a Application for my Company, and here all use pretty new technologie